# calculate standard deviation of window of 100 days in a data having 2000 points

Tags: r, standard-deviation, rolling-computation

I have 2000 data points and i want to calculate the standard deviation for all the windows of size 100 days, I am getting a few NA values. can anybody suggest an edit.
here the link to the csv:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NnavFM_FAXIGIyHsNXBbOpoysJYlGnm8/view?usp=sharing

```
df<- read.csv("BSE_DAX_DCC.csv")
nrow(df)
sd1=c()
for (i in 1:200){
duration = df[(100*(i-1)+1):100*(i),'corr']
sd1[i]=sd(duration)

}
sd1
```

Answer (score 0):

This calculates the mean of the 100 rows centered around the current point (or fewer rows if there are fewer rows avalailable).  You could add the `align=` argument (see `?rollapply`) but if you align to the right or left then there will be one row having only one point and `sd` of one point is NA.

```
library(zoo)
transform(df, mean = rollapply(corr, 100, sd, partial = TRUE))
```

Using a smaller example for clarity:

```
rollapply(1:5, 3, sd, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 0.7071068 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.7071068

# same
c(sd(1:2), sd(1:3), sd(2:4), sd(3:5), sd(4:5))
## [1] 0.7071068 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.7071068
```

Comment: hey i guess you didnt understand my question. I want to calculate standard deviation of 200 samples taking 100 points in each of the sample. Your code is calculating some mean value for each of the 2000 data point

Comment: Suggest you read the answer again. I had changed it from mean to sd.